# Finding questions to answer

Tags: sql, sql-server, stackexchange

In light of the recent *"SQL frenzy"* of sorts in The 2nd Monitor, I decided to take a stab at writing my own SEDE query. Essentially, what it does is find questions that could be answered based on the following parameters.

```
-- @MinQuestionVotes - The minimum amount of votes on a question.
-- @MaxQuestionAnswers - The maximum amount of answers to a question.
-- @QuestionTags - The tags that should be on the questions.
```

At the moment, I feel that those parameters are necessary for finding possible questions to answer, but if you feel that one isn't needed, just mention it. Anyways, here's the code, and here's the [SEDE query link](http://data.stackexchange.com/codereview/revision/325583/420892/finding-unaccepted-questions-to-answer).

```sql
-- User parameters for finding questions. Here is
-- a brief description of what each parameter does.

  -- @MinQuestionVotes - The minimum amount of votes on a question.
  -- @MaxQuestionAnswers - The maximum amount of answers to a question.
  -- @QuestionTags - The tags that should be on the questions.
DECLARE @MinQuestionVotes INT = ##MinQuestionVotes##;
DECLARE @MaxQuestionAnswers INT = ##MaxQuestionAnswers##;
DECLARE @QuestionTags NVARCHAR(150) = ##QuestionTag1##;


-- SELECT the final results. Data is filtered based
-- on the following conditions.

  -- ClosedDate  IS EQUAL TO              null
  -- PostTypeId  IS EQUAL TO              question
  -- Score       GREATER THAN OR EQUAL TO @MinQuestionVotes
  -- AnswerCount LESS THAN OR EQUAL TO    @MaxQuestionAnswers
  -- Tags        CONTAIN                  @QuestionTags
SELECT
    Posts.Id AS [Post Link]
  , OwnerUserId AS [User Link]
  , Posts.Score
  , Posts.Tags
  , Posts.ViewCount
  , Posts.AnswerCount
  FROM Posts 
    INNER JOIN PostTags ON Posts.Id = PostTags.PostId
    INNER JOIN Tags ON PostTags.TagId = Tags.Id
  WHERE
    Posts.PostTypeId = 1 AND
    Posts.ClosedDate IS NULL AND
    Posts.Score >= @MinQuestionVotes AND
    Posts.AnswerCount <= @MaxQuestionAnswers AND
    Tags.TagName LIKE CONCAT('%', @QuestionTags, '%');
```

Finally, here's an example of possible inputs. When entering into the `QuestionTags` field, you need to surround your tags with **single** quotes, like this: `'python'`.

```
@MinQuestionVotes:   1
@MaxQuestionAnswers: 0
@QuestionTags:       'python'
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, your comments:

They're structured well, but, the content could be improved:

> ```
> -- SELECT the final results. Data is filtered based
>    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> -- on the following conditions.
> ```

You're not really `SELECT`ing the *final* results, you `SELECT` them based on the conditions, you don't `SELECT` them and then filter them.

---

Your declaration `DECLARE @QuestionTags NVARCHAR(150) = ##QuestionTag1##` is a little confusing:
`Tags` is plural, but then the variable you ask for input is `Tag1` (*singular*)?

---

You ask for input like `##MinQuestionVotes##`, but there's no reason to abbreviate, it could really just be:
`##MinimumQuestionVotes##`. Same things applies to the other two.

---

Finally, `CONCAT('%', @QuestionTags, '%')` is good, but you could really just:
`'%' + @QuestionTags + '%'` instead.

You could even build the tag string with the `'` attached so the user doesn't need to input.

---

Other than that, your code looks really clean and nice. Good Work!

Answer (score 4):

Due to the way you used the `##QuestionTag1##` parameter, you have to enter `'java'` in the input field (with the single quotes) rather than `java`.  I'm pretty sure that that is an indicator of an SQL injection vulnerability.

But [java](/questions/tagged/java) is not [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript).  I don't see why you mangle the tag name with wildcards.