# Finding questions to answer - Part 2

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stackexchange

I've refactored [my previous question finder](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/93545/finding-questions-to-answer), and added multi-tag support, and support for searching for keywords in the question titles. Essentially, what it does is find questions that could be answered based on the following parameters.

```
-- @MinimumQuestionVotes - The minimum amount of votes on a question.
-- @MaximumQuestionAnswers - The maximum amount of answers to a question.
-- @QuestionTags - The question's tags. Blank string is a wildcard.
-- @TitleContains - Words in the title. Blank string is a wildcard.
```

If you feel that any parameters aren't needed, or can be improved, just mention it. I'm open to any suggestions. Anyways, here's the code, and here's the [SEDE query link](http://data.stackexchange.com/codereview/revision/327760/423476/finding-questions-to-answer-part-2).

```sql
-- User parameters for finding questions. Here is
-- a brief description of what each parameter does.

  -- @MinimumQuestionVotes - The minimum amount of votes on a question.
  -- @MaximumQuestionAnswers - The maximum amount of answers to a question.
  -- @QuestionTags - The question's tags. Blank string is a wildcard.
  -- @TitleContains - Words in the title. Blank string is a wildcard.
DECLARE @MinimumQuestionVotes INT = ##MinimumQuestionVotes:int?0##;
DECLARE @MaximumQuestionAnswers INT = ##MaximumQuestionAnswers:int?0##;
DECLARE @QuestionTags NVARCHAR(150) = ##QuestionTags##;
DECLARE @TitleContains NVARCHAR(250) = ##TitleContains##;


-- Final results are SELECTed based on the following
-- conditions.

  -- ClosedDate  IS EQUAL TO              null
  -- PostTypeId  IS EQUAL TO              question
  -- Score       GREATER THAN OR EQUAL TO @MinimimQuestionVotes
  -- AnswerCount LESS THAN OR EQUAL TO    @MaximumQuestionAnswers
  -- Tags        CONTAIN                  @QuestionTags
SELECT
    [Posts].Id AS [Post Link]
  , [Posts].OwnerUserId AS [User Link]
  , [Posts].Score
  , [Posts].Tags
  , [Posts].ViewCount
  , [Posts].AnswerCount
  FROM Posts WHERE
        [Posts].ClosedDate IS NULL
    AND [Posts].PostTypeId = 1
    AND [Posts].Score >= @MinimumQuestionVotes
    AND [Posts].AnswerCount <= @MaximumQuestionAnswers
    AND [Posts].Tags LIKE '%' + REPLACE(@QuestionTags, ' ', '%%') + '%'
    AND [Posts].Title LIKE '%' + REPLACE(@TitleContains, ' ', '%%') + '%'
  ORDER BY Score DESC;
```

Finally, here's some example input for the parameters. Do note, in the `@QuestionTags` and `@TitleContains` fields, you need to put single quotes, `''`, and space-separate each tag/word.

```
@MinimumQuestionVotes:   1
@MaximumQuestionAnswers: 0
@QuestionTags:           'python beginner'
@TitleContains:          'web'
```

Comment: your query doesn't work with empty `@QuestionTags` or `@TitleContains` unless you put single quotes in.

Comment: @Lyle'sMug That's one of the quirks of the SEDE. You have to put in raw variable values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are some usability issues with `@QuestionTags`:

- The ordering of tags matters. I think in the typical use case that's not the desired behavior
- The input format is hackish (the implementation too) and unintuitive

I have an alternative suggestion that has different downsides:

- Use multiple tag input fields, for example `@Tag1`, `@Tag2`, and so on
- The advantage is that you could enter tags in any order, and without funky input rules
- The disadvantage is that the number of tags you can enter will be limited to the number of fields you provide
- Note that this approach will also open the possibility to choose the condition for for matching tags: they can be AND-ed or OR-ed. Your choice, or give another input to users to let them decide

The numbered fields are not exactly pretty, but I think the query will be easier to use this way. (Can be subjective.)

You could do similarly for matching keywords in the title.

Note that I dropped "Question" from the parameter names, to simplify to `@TagN`. On the network only questions can have tags, so this is obvious.

Other notes:

- The semicolons at the end of variable declarations are unnecessary
- It would be nice to make title optional
- The repeated `[Posts].` prefix of fields are not necessary, and a bit of a noise

[Example implementation](http://data.stackexchange.com/codereview/revision/327807/423546/finding-questions-to-answer-part-2) with some of the improvements explained above:

```
DECLARE @MinimumQuestionVotes INT = ##MinimumQuestionVotes:int?0##
DECLARE @MaximumQuestionAnswers INT = ##MaximumQuestionAnswers:int?0##
DECLARE @Tag1 NVARCHAR(50) = RTRIM(LTRIM(##Tag1:string? ##))
DECLARE @Tag2 NVARCHAR(50) = RTRIM(LTRIM(##Tag2:string? ##))
DECLARE @Tag3 NVARCHAR(50) = RTRIM(LTRIM(##Tag3:string? ##))
DECLARE @TitleContains NVARCHAR(250) = RTRIM(LTRIM(##TitleContains:string? ##))

SELECT
    Id AS [Post Link]
  , OwnerUserId AS [User Link]
  , Score
  , Tags
  , ViewCount
  , AnswerCount
  FROM Posts WHERE
        ClosedDate IS NULL
    AND PostTypeId = 1
    AND Score >= @MinimumQuestionVotes
    AND AnswerCount <= @MaximumQuestionAnswers
    AND (@Tag1 = '' OR Tags LIKE '%' + @Tag1 + '%')
    AND (@Tag2 = '' OR Tags LIKE '%' + @Tag2 + '%')
    AND (@Tag3 = '' OR Tags LIKE '%' + @Tag3 + '%')
    AND (@TitleContains = '' OR Title LIKE '%' + REPLACE(@TitleContains, ' ', '%%') + '%')
  ORDER BY Score DESC;
```

Answer (score 3):

Your code's looking really good!

I can only really see a few things that could be improved.

---

> ```
> SELECT  
>   [Posts].Id AS [Post Link]
> , [Posts].OwnerUserId AS [User Link]
> ```

into:

```
SELECT
  [Posts].Id [Post Link]
, [Posts].OwnerUserId [User Link]
```

`AS` is optional, [see this answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/87046/62429) for some more elaboration on why it's unnecessary and cluttery.

---

> ```
> ORDER BY Score DESC;
> ```

I would add another `ORDER` to that, and make it `ORDER BY Score DESC, ViewCount DESC;`

---

When working from/with a single table (`Posts`), you can either prefix `[Posts].` to the beginning of your column requests, or just omit it entirely.

However, in the `ORDER`, you change the continous use of this and opt for vanilla `Score`, rather than `[Posts].Score`.

It's best if you choose one method (*I'd suggest not attaching `[Posts].`*), and stick with it.

---

Other than that, your code looks really neat and nice. Good work!